# Magento overriding the email header and footer

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am working on new Magento project. Basically I want to modify  Magento's default email header/footer.

I have noticed  that [one question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67800/how-to-create-custom-email-header) posted  related to this, but it doesn't seems to be properly answered.

I have added my code below

**app/code/local/Toystore/Common/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
   <modules.............>
     .......................
   </modules>
   <global>
      <helpers>
          ...............................
      </helpers>
      <template>
         <email>
            <design_email_header2 translate="label" module="toystore_common">
                <label>Email - Header</label>
                <file>html/headercustom.html</file>
                <type>text</type>
            </design_email_header2>
          <design_email_footer2 translate="label" module="toystore_common">
              <label>Email - Footer</label>
              <file>html/footercustom.html</file>
         <type>text</type>
         </design_email_footer2>
         </email>
         </template>
         </global>
  </config>
```

And in my template I have added like following to call this

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header2"}}
```

And my html files resides in 
**app/locale/en_US/template/email/html/headercustom.html**

I am not sure why its not calling my new file, because the email is coming without header.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You just need to edit the config at System > Configurations > Visual > Transactional Emails